# Сортировка объекта в массиве

Tags: silex

В моем цикле for на данный момент выводятся абсолютно все объекты:

```
<div id="sales-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body
           {% for sale in event.sales %}
            <img src="/images/sales/{{ sale.photo }}">
            <p>{{ sale.name }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне надо чтобы в модальном окне выводились не все объекты, а только один объект с одной картинкой и именем. Пример с желаемым результатом - [example](http://old.annualghac.com/page/7th_ghac_guest_speakers)  Подскажите, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: причем тут angularjs?

Comment: @Grundy, не туда нажал при выборе тега.

Comment: _выводились не все объекты, а только один объект_ - как это связано с _сортировкой_, которая указана в заголовке?